# Android AudioTrack Error:uninitialized AudioTrack

Tags: android, audiotrack

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    int minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, 
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

  audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, 
        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM); 


    playfilesound();
}


private void playfilesound() throws IOException
{




    int count = 512 * 1024; // 512 kb
    //Reading the file..
    byte[] byteData = null; 
    File file = null; 
    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/"+"recordsound");    //filePath


    byteData = new byte[(int)count];
    FileInputStream in = null;
    try {
    in = new FileInputStream( file );

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }


    int bytesread = 0, ret = 0;
    int size = (int) file.length();
    audioTrack.play();



    while (bytesread < size) {    // Write the byte array to the track 
        ret = in.read( byteData,0, count);   //ret =size in bytes

        if (ret != -1) {
            audioTrack.write(byteData,0, ret);
            bytesread += ret; }  //ret
        else break; 

    }   //while



    in.close();
   audioTrack.stop(); audioTrack.release();
    }
```

I used the debugger to step through the code and hover abover audioTrack, it's allocated and inited.  The file also exists.

But when it hits audioTrack.play()  it throws an error of saying its illegal state exception, unintilized AudioTrack.

I enclosed the project which includes the recording file part. 
http://www.mediafire.com/?6i2r3whg7e7rs79

Answer (score 2):

The configuration of the channel you use is discontinued, in the place of `AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO` Uses `AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO` To record and `AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO` to play...

Comment: Please use English and only English here on SO.

Comment: Por favor, utilice el inglés y sólo el inglés aquí en SO.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you called play before you write! Try this ...

```
int bytesread = 0, ret = 0;
int size = (int) file.length();
//audioTrack.play();  <---- play called prematurely



while (bytesread < size) {    // Write the byte array to the track 
    ret = in.read( byteData,0, count);   //ret =size in bytes

    if (ret != -1) {
        audioTrack.write(byteData,0, ret);
        bytesread += ret; 
        audioTrack.play(); //<--- try calling it here!
    }  //ret
    else break; 

}   //while
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got more than one problems here:

- The discontinued channel part has been answered yet.
- Don't play the audio on the UI thread!

*Please also format your code.*

EDIT:
I also added

```
android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_AUDIO);
```

to make the playback more soft.
Then you can set it to default again:

```
android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
```